# Escape the dungeon, by deciphering the codes and navigating the rooms to find a way out

Tags: logical-deduction, cipher, password

You have been thrown into a dungeon with many rooms; you don't know who did this or why.

You start in room 37. You might be thinking "Why 37?", so I will explain this: "Why not?"

You need to find the way out of this place.

Of course, there is a lot of data that are encrypted in your way. Some of the data are really simple and easy to decode like "**the first prime**" or "**0x30**". Some of them are very hard, like "**☏☀☑☀☂☇☔☓☄**". All the data that should be decrypted by you in your journey are in **bold** text.

Most of rooms have exits to other rooms, however you will need to discover to which rooms. Note that if there is a way from room A to room B this DO NOT imply that there is a way from room B to room A. I.E. you should consider every passage as one-way only. A two-way passage is explicitly represented as a pair or two one-way only passages.

Post an answer explaining your movements step-by-step and room-by-room in order to successfully escape the dungeon. Do not forget to explain what items you collected on your journey and how you used them. Explain how you dealt with the trouble that you encountered. And of course, the most important: Explain how you decrypted all the **boldtext** secret data! I will accept the first answer that do all of this correctly, without gaps, errors or cheating.

Beware: I expect that this puzzle to be really hard, as in fact it is a series of puzzles in one.

And please, please. DO NOT FORGET TO POST YOUR ANSWERS IN SPOILER TAGS!

To put your answers in spoiler tags, you should add `>!` to the start of the lines inside your spoiler. To insert line breaks inside your spoiler tags, add a `<br>` in the end of the line.

<sup>Note: Feel free to edit this to fix possible spelling, grammar or punctuation errors, as long as it does not changes the **bold** text parts, except when obvious in clear english.</sup>

---

[Edited, long time after solved]: Made only somewhat spoilery rooms protected by spoilers. If you want to show them all, run this javascript: `$(".postcell blockquote").removeClass("spoiler");`. If you want to hide them all, run this other one: `$(".postcell blockquote").addClass("spoiler");`.

---

Here are the rooms. Remember, you starts out in the 37:

### Room 1:

> That is the exit and the princess is already here just waiting for you!
>  Sure that the evil wizard was defeated, you and the princess walks out of the dungeon, going back to the castle.
>  And they lived happily ever after. ❤
>  The end!

### Room 2:

> You found a "**☏☀☑☀☂☇☔☓☄**". Strange, why the heck you would need this? You get it anyway.
>   Now go to the room numbered as **the cube of this room**.

### Room 4:

> A giant plutonium dragon comes from nowhere, put you in his mouth, crush your bones with his diamond jaw and eats you.
>  In his stomach, a boiling acid jet dissolves your body in a few seconds.
>  Game Over.

### Room 5:

> There is a man here. He said that he name is Caesar and he shares a secret to you. This secret is "**kwws=22elw1o|24vSg{I}**". What do this means?
>   There is a ventilation tube leading to the **tri-hepta**.
>   There is a strange device, called "**sfuspqfmfu**" but it does not works. If you manage to activate it somehow, it will lead you to room **11110**.
>   There is window leading to room "**how many legs there is in a chair?**"
>   There is a big door leading to room "**ruof-ytrihT**".

### Room 8:

> There is a whirlpool in this room.
>   If you are unable to cope with it, you will be sucked through a hole direct to **a room which the number divided by two is rounded to the number of this room**.
>   If you can somehow stop it, you may grab a hook and crawl into the **perfect room**.

### Room 10:

> There is an arrow in this room, you decided to take it. There is something written in the arrow: "**这是一个红色的鲱鱼 - Made in China**".
>   There are three buttons: red, blue and yellow. You don't see any exit here, so what button do you press?

### Room 12:

> There is a door that leads to the **Z** room.
>   There are four pills here:
>   If you eat the red pill, you will be sent to the "**naM hsaM**" room.
>   If you eat the blue pill, you will be sent to the "**ロコン**" room.
>   If you eat the orange pill, you will be sent to the "**Pidgeotto**" room.
>   If you eat the white pill, you will be sent to the **21120110122101211011201112** room.
>   Warning: Pills do not respawn! So if you come back to this room later, the pills already taken won't be here again. I.E. you can't eat the same pill twice!
>   EDITED: If you take a pill, you need to eat it. You can't take all the pills at once and eat them somewhere else.

### Room 13:

> You found a "**D**". Now leave using "**the same door that you used to come in**".

### Room 17:

> The floor mysteriously disappears, leaving a dark bottomless pit where you instantaneously fall, forever!
>  Game Over.

### Room 18:

> There are three doors:
>   The left door goes to the **iron room**.
>   The front door to **the room where you started**.
>   In the ceiling, there is a big green steel locked door. If you are able to unlock it, it will lead you to the **first prime** room.

### Room 21:

> You found a "**Красный ключ**".
>   There are four tunnels here:
>   The left tunnel leads to room "**square of the first prime**".
>   The middle tunnel leads to the **room with the pills**.
>   The right tunnel leads to the **0x30** room.
>   The tunnel in the back leads to the **room made by repeated numbers**.

### Room 23:

> You found a magic bean!
>   There is a sign in this room: "**◓●◒◒◙ ◔◈◉◓ ◉◓ ◁ ◒◅◄ ◈◅◒◒◉◎◇**"
>   Two exits. The left one leads to room "**@@@@@@@@**". The right to room **XLVIII**.

### Room 24:

> There is a huge lion here. If you can't kill him quickly enough, you will become his dinner.
>   Behind the lion, should you be able to avoid him, there are two stairs:
>   The stairs going up leads to the room "**Monica, Erica, Rita, Tina, Sandra, Mary, Jessica**".
>   There is a massive red steel door which needs a red key. If you are able to open it, there is a stairs going down leading to the **bad luck room**.

### Room 26:

> You found a powerful gun. There is just one bullet there.
>  
>   There is a window that leads to room "**Butterfree**".
>   There are two doors: The left one leads to room "**neetneves**" and the right one leads to the **iron room**.

### Room 28:

> WHOA! You found a big pot of gold!
>  Now, proceed to the **room of that girls**.

### Room 30:

> The front door leads to the room which the number is **THE answer**!
>   There is a window in the wall, but it is too small for you to pass through.
>   Looking through the window, you see some trees out there. There is a bullseye near one of the trees.
>   If you have the **needed equipment (what is it?)**, you may shoot the bullseye.

### Room 34:

> You found the blue key!
>   There is a spring that may throw you away to the room "**Mg**".
>   There is a closet that is a secret passage to the room which is **a multiple of 11**.

### Room 37:

> There is a blue box, but it is locked. You need to find a blue key to open it.
>   Two doors. The left door goes to room "**Argon**". The right goes to room "**Micro Mike**".

### Room 40:

> You found the cake!
>  This cake is so delicious and moist!
>  Now you can walk back to **the previous room** or go to the **"Yt4$)"** room.

### Room 42:

> There is a gnome in this room.
>   He said: "If you give me a pot of gold and a magic bean, I will make a rainbow! Everybody knows that there is a pot of gold in the end of the rainbow!"
>   Curious, you decide to ask for more information. So, he tells this:
>   "I used to be a prisoner in a dungeon just like you. But then, I took an arrow to the knee."
>   ! Anyway, in this room there is a river called Tiber (why is the name of the river important?), leading to room **X**.

### Room 44:

> You found a glowing crystal key!
>   There are a window leading the **room with the largest number**.
>   There is an elevator leading to the **first room with a number greater than this one**.

### Room 48:

> A giant circular fast-spinning blade falls onto your head.
>  Then, your body is divided in two halves!
>  Guess what? You got a nice Game Over!

### Room 56:

> You found a black magic book and got it. Then you are teleported back to **the starting room**.
>   If you already have been in this room before and had already taken the book, you will be teleported to the room **whose number is the first two-digit room number appearing in π**.

### Room 59:

> You found something **TERRA**. Guess what it could be?
>   Now choose your way out: "**dezessete**" or "**dezoito**".

### Room 63:

> Congratulations, you won a million dollars!
>  Now you just need to leave this dungeon and you are a rich man!
>  There is an escalator going up here. It leads to the **room with repeated numbers**.
>  There is a door to the left it leads to the room **0x4**.

### Blue box:

> You found the batteries for the "**84 69 76 69 80 79 82 84 69 82**"!

### Shooting the bullseye:

> You shoot through the window, and hit the bullseye just in the middle!
>  Immediately, a new trapdoor opens in the room **1A**. This trapdoor leads to the room "**五十六**".

### Red button:

> You pressed the RED button:
>  BOOOOOM!!!! Game over!
>  You should know that this always happens when you press a red button!

### Blue button:

> You pressed the BLUE button:
>  An elephant comes out of nowhere and tramples you. Game over!

### Yellow button:

> You pressed the YELLOW button:
>  A secret passage opens in that "**ending with '3s2 3p6'**" room. It leads to room "**◔◈◅ ◌●◒◄ ◉◓ ◍◙ ◓◈◅◐◅◒◄, ◉ ◌◁◃○ ◎●◔◈◉◎◇**".
>  A trapdoor opens under you feet. You fell onto the room "**NPPSTVPJWFSQFIUGPGMBITJSFCNVOFIUFTPIX**".

### If you decide to insert the arrow in your own knee:

> Seriously? Are you crazy? What the hell are you thinking?
>  The arrow was poisoned. You became paralyzed. Your skin turns blue.
>  You fell to the ground in a deep pain and agony. You can't breath and your heart stops.
>  Congratulations! That was the most stupid thing that you could do in this game!
>  Guess what you got now? A giant, red, blinking and dancing "game over"! That is right dude, you lost the game and died for being so stupid!

### Magic book:

> In the book, it is written:
>   
>   Abrakadabra!
>   **. ορετόσσιρεπ ιχό ιεσάρδ αν ιεπέρπ αθ ςασ ήγρΟ ! άρεν ανέμγαρατ ατ όπα ωνάπ υομ ήμανύδ ητ ιαμύολακιπε , ςανώδιεσοΠ .**

### Giving the gold and the magic bean to the gnome:

> The gnome receives the gold and the magic bean and a rainbow appeared right in front of your eyes, entering in the pot of gold.
>  You started to walk over it. That is incredible! You did not knew that you could walk over a rainbow!
>  You thanks the gnome and go away, walking over the rainbow into the blue sky.
>  The view here is so beautiful! You can see mountains, rivers and cities down there...
>  But then, you perceived something:
>  You leaved the dungeon! Congratulations! You are free!
>  And then, you remembered still another great thing:
>  Rainbows do not lasts for long time!
>  The rainbow disappears under your feet, and you fall, quickly going directly to the ground.
>  Oh no, you will face certain death! **Except if...?**

Comment: Wow, great idea! Love it!

Comment: Disappointed that I can't use the parachute in room 17 :)

Comment: @Lopsy Well thought. :)

Comment: Will you give feedback for partial answers, or should we hold off posting until we've found a complete way out of the dungeon?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, I will give feedback on partial answers.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why all the rooms are in spoiler quotes? It makes it harder to browse through them, and we're going to have to do that anyway to solve the puzzle (so they're not exactly spoilers). Could they just be in regular quotes or no quotes?

Comment: @doppelgreener No strong reason. I just thought it could be more interesting this way if you happens to be exploring the dungeon reading the rooms as you discover them. So, yes, they could be just quotes.

Comment: @doppelgreener You may just open your browser console and run `$(".postcell blockquote").removeClass("spoiler");`. In the next question of this series, I will make it visible in blockquotes and put the inverse command `$(".postcell blockquote").addClass("spoiler");` for people who want to see the rooms as they explore them.

Comment: Regards room 8: the usual convention for rounding is to round halves *up*, but that room doesn't exist.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So here is my stab at this. I promise I did not look at any of Lopsy's work.

## The Codes

> Room 2: **☏☀☑☀☂☇☔☓☄**, Subtracting 9727 from the [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) code points gives numbers, which correspond to the letters `Parachute`.
>  Room 2: **the cube of this room**, is `8`.
>  Room 5: **kwws=22elw1o|24vSg{I}**, is a [Caesar cypher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). Subtracting 3 from each character gives `http://bit.ly/1sPdxFz` which shows [a bunch of troll faces](http://bit.ly/1sPdxFz) (red herring).
>  Room 5: **tri-hepta**, `tri` is for 3 and `hepta` for 7, so I'm gonna venture a guess and say that's `37`. I've never used this door, though.
>  Room 5: **sfuspqfmfu**, decrementing each character by 1 and reversing the string spells `teleporter`.
>  Room 5: **11110**, is binary for `30`.
>  Room 5: **How many legs there is in a chair?**, I hope that's `4`.
>  Room 5: **ruof-ytrihT**, that's `34` backwards.
>  Room 8: **a room which the number divided by two is rounded to the number of this room**, is `17` (could be `16` but that doesn't exist).
>  Room 8: **perfect room**. I'm very unsure about this one, but I'm gonna guess 21, because it's the perfect score in Black Jack. **Edit:** Now I *have* looked at Lopsy's solutions. ...facepalm... [Perfect numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) were my first thought, but looking at the Wikipedia article I overlooked `28` and thought they went `6`, `496`, `8128`... I'm gonna count this one as "solved correctly, but too blind". I've shortened the way out correspondingly.
>  Room 10: **这是一个红色的鲱鱼**, mean `This is a red herring` in Chinese.
>  Room 12: **Z**, I believe this is just room `26` (alphabet and stuff).
>  Room 12: **naM hsaM**, "Mash Man" is game number `37` in [Action 52](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_52).
>  Room 12: **ロコン**, is the Japanese name of Pokémon [Vulpix](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Vulpix_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), with Pokédex number `37`.
>  Room 12: **Pidgeotto**, is also a Pokémon, [with Pokédex number](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pidgeotto_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) `17`.
>  Room 12: **21120110122101211011201112**, This is [Morse code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code). `0` are separators, `1` short and `2` long signals. It spells `XIPLUV` which is `VULPIX` backwards. So this is another `37`.
>  Room 13: **D**, that looks like a `Bow` to me!
>  Room 13: **the same door that you used to come in**, I think only `24` has a door leading to 13.
>  Room 18: **Iron room**, new guess: this is just `26` (the atomic number of [Iron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron)) in parallel to the *Argon* hint.
>  Room 18: **the room where you started**, is `37`.
>  Room 18: **the first prime**, is `2`.
>  Room 21: **Красный ключ**, is Russian for `Red key` (you have no idea how proud I was to be able to read that myself, despite my very rudimentary Russian lessons being some 6-10 years in the past :D). 
>  Room 21: **square of the first prime**, is `4`.
>  Room 21: **room with the pills**, is room `12`.
>  Room 21: **0x30**, is hexadecimal notation for `48`.
>  Room 21: **room made by repeated numbers**, I believe "numbers" refers to the "digits" in the room number, so this would be `44`.
>  Room 23: **◓●◒◒◙ ◔◈◉◓ ◉◓ ◁ ◒◅◄ ◈◅◒◒◉◎◇**, Subtracting 9600 from each Unicode code point yields `SORRY THIS IS A RED HERRING`.
>  Room 23: **@@@@@@@@**, There's 8 of them, so that's just room `8`.
>  Room 23: **XLVIII**, Roman numeral for `48`.
>  Room 24: **Monica, Erica, Rita, Tina, Sandra, Mary, Jessica**, is from [Mambo No.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mambo_No._5) `5` (as a German, I didn't even have to look that up thanks to Lou Bega's cover^^).
>  Room 24: **bad luck room**, this has got to be `13`, being the unlucky number.
>  Room 26: **Butterfree**, yet another Pokémon [with Pokédex number](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Butterfree_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) `12`.
>  Room 26: **neetneves**, is `17` backwards.
>  Room 26: **iron room**, so if my guess above is right, then this door leads to `26` itself.
>  Room 28: **room of that girls**, I think this refers back to the hint for Mambo No. `5`.
>  Room 30: **THE answer**, should be [the answer to life, the universe and everything](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=the+answer+to+life%2C+the+universe+and+everything&oq=the+answer+to+life%2C+the+universe+and+everything&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3.255j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8): `42`.
>  Room 34: **Mg**, is symbol for [Magnesium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium), with atomic number `12`.
>  Room 34: **multiple of 11**, that's `44`.
>  Room 37: **Argon**, has [atomic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon) `18`.
>  Room 37: **Micro Mike**, another game from Action 52, with number `24`.
>  Room 40: [The **cake** is a lie.](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/the-cake-is-a-lie) There's no way to get to this room, and therefore the **Yt4$)** likely doesn't mean anything at all.
>  Room 42: **X**, I thought this could be 24 as the 24th letter of the alphabet, or it could be `10` as a Roman numeral. I went with the latter, because I didn't find another way into room 10, and because the [Tiber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiber) runs through Rome (then again, the alphabet in question *is* the Latin alphabet ;)).
>  Room 44: **room with the largest number**, is `63`.
>  Room 44: **first room with a number greater than this one**, is `48`.
>  Room 56: **the starting room**, is `37`.
>  Room 56: **the room whose number is the first two-digit room number appearing in π**, is `59`.
>  Room 59: **TERRA**, is a [ROT-13 cypher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) of "GREEN" so this is the `Green key`.
>  Room 59: **dezessete**, Portuguese for `17`.
>  Room 59: **dezoito**, Portuguese for `18`.
>  Room 63: **room with repeated numbers**, again, I believe this refers to the digits, so that's `44`.
>  Room 63: **0x4**, should be hexadecimal notation, which is just `4`.
>  Blue box: **84 69 76 69 80 79 82 84 69 82**, ASCII codes of `TELEPORTER`.
>  Bullseye: **1A**, I'm hoping is also hexadecimal, which would be `26`.
>  Bullseye: **五十六**, Japanese (I think?) for `56`.
>  Yellow button: **ending with '3s2 3p6'**, could refer to the [electron configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration) of *Argon*, which would be `18` again.
>  Yellow button: **◔◈◅ ◌●◒◄ ◉◓ ◍◙ ◓◈◅◐◅◒◄, ◉ ◌◁◃○ ◎●◔◈◉◎◇**, subtracting 9600 from the Unicode code points gives `THE LORD IS MY SHEPERD, I LACK NOTHING` which is in [Psalm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psalm_23) `23`.
>  Yellow button: **NPPSTVPJWFSQFIUGPGMBITJSFCNVOFIUFTPIX**, decrement each letter by 1 and reverse the string to get `WHOSETHENUMBERISHALFOFTHEPREVIOUSROOM`. Since the button is in room 10, and (I think) the only way to get there is from 42, this is `21`.
>  Magic book: **. ορετόσσιρεπ ιχό ιεσάρδ αν ιεπέρπ αθ ςασ ήγρΟ ! άρεν ανέμγαρατ ατ όπα ωνάπ υομ ήμανύδ ητ ιαμύολακιπε , ςανώδιεσοΠ .** Reverse this to get *actual* Greek. It translates to `Neptune, I invoke my power over troubled waters! Rage you should act no more.`, so the book can be used to tame the whirlpool. I swear this is a reference to [The Tempest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tempest).
>  Rainbow: **Except if...?**, you've got a parachute...

Phew... that's out of the way. Let's get out of this dungeon!

## The Long Way Out

> First, I think `44` is a dead end, because it leads to `48` (instant death), and `63`, which in turn leads only back to `44` or to `4` (instant death). Furthermore, you don't need either glowing crystal key, nor any money. Likewise, `1` is probably a red herring, I don't think there's a way to get to it. Furthermore, there's no evil wizard, and the puzzle doesn't require me to rescue a princess. `40` also cannot be reached.
>
>  Let's go!
>
>  37 -> Go to 18
>  18 -> Go to 26
>  26 -> Take gun, go to 26. *(because I can!)*
>  26 -> Go to 26. *(because I can!)*
>  26 -> Go to 26. *(because I can!)*
>  26 -> Go to 12.
>  12 -> Red pill to 37.
>  37 -> Go to 24.
>  24 -> Kill lion with gun, go to 5
>  5 -> Go to 34
>  34 -> Take blue key, go to 12
>  12 -> Blue pill to 37.
>  37 -> Unlock blue box, take batteries, go to 24
>  24 -> Go to 5.
>  5 -> Plug batteries in teleporter, go to 30
>  30 -> Go to 42
>  42 -> Go to 10
>  10 -> Take arrow, press yellow (opens door in 18 to 23), go to 21
>  21 -> Take red key, go to 12
>  12 -> White pill to 37
>  37 -> Go to 24
>  24 -> Unlock red door, go to 13
>  13 -> Take the bow, go to 24
>  24 -> Go to 5
>  5 -> Use teleporter to go to 30
>  30 -> Shoot bullseye with bow and arrow, to open trapdoor in 26 to 56, go to 42
>  42 -> Go to 10
>  10 -> Go to 21
>  21 -> Go to 12
>  12 -> Door to 26
>  26 -> Use trapdoor to 56
>  56 -> Take Magic Book, go to 37
>  37 -> Go to 18
>  18 -> Secret passage to 23.
>  23 -> Take magic bean, go to 8.
>  8 -> Use Magic Book, go to 28
>  28 -> Take pot of gold, go to 5
>  5 -> Go to 34
>  34 -> Go to 12
>  12 -> Door to 26
>  26 -> Trapdoor to 56
>  56 -> This time go to 59
>  59 -> Take green key, go to 18
>  18 -> Unlock green door, go to 2
>  2 -> Take Parachute, go to 8
>  8 -> Use Magic Book, go to 28
>  28 -> Go to 5
>  5 -> Use teleporter to go to 30
>  30 -> Go to 42
>  42 -> Give gold to gnome
>  Rainbow -> Use parachute to survive the fall and land somewhere safely outside the dungeon!

**Woohoo!**

I believe there's a shorter way through the dungeon (especially the second half), but this one does the trick. Thanks to Victor for a couple of hints when I was making things more complicated then they were. :)

Comment: Almost right, you are very close to the solution, but there are still a few errors. You already discovered your failure about the perfect room. You didn't get the iron room right. 21120110122101211011201112 is being harder than it was supposed to be, I got it inspired in some other question here (which was solved). About `@@@@@@@@`, I can't tell yet.

Comment: **CONGRATULATIONS!!!!** Answer accepted! :) Now a last challenge: Create a part 2 of this puzzle, or a derivative like escape the castle, save the princess, escape the planet...

Comment: @Victor Heh, thanks a lot. It's been good fun! I think I've spent as much time as I can justify on this for this weekend, but I might get back to coming up with a follow-up over the next weeks. ;) (Let's delete some of these comments. Leave the last one. :))

Comment: I wish I could upvote twice for the hyperlink references. :)

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but how do you encode symbols in a caesar cipher? For room 5 you decode kwws=22elw1o|24vSg{I} to be http://bit.ly/1sPdxFz. Did you use a website to do this?

Comment: @DeeCeptor I don't recall exactly, but I probably wrote some code for it, like [this CJam script](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%7Bi32-%2092%2B%2095%25%2032%2B%20c%7D%2F&input=kwws%3D22elw1o%7C24vSg%7BI%7D) where I kept fiddling with the `92` until I got something that looked good. Although I guess the `kwws=22` being isomorph to `http://` may have been hint enough to figure out the right offset immediately (I really don't remember at this point).

Answer (score 5):

OK, this is going to take a while.

I think this answer correctly escapes the dungeon now. However, there are still some unsolved mysteries (in particular, the identity of the iron room).

### 1. You just have to kill the lion

> Go to 18 (atomic number of **Argon**). This room has an exit to the (**iron room**) and so does room 26, so presumably we can get from 18 to 26. Pick up the gun. We see exits to 17 (**neetneves** spelled backwards) and 12 (**Butterfree**'s Pokedex number). Proceed to 12. Take all the pills. Retrace your steps all the way back to your starting point and go to 24 (**Micro Mike**'s Action 52 index). Shoot the lion and ravage its corpse.

### 2. You only have to get a million dollars

> Go to 5 (**Monica etc** is from some song with 5 in the title). Proceed to 34 (**rouf-ytrihT** backwards) and pick up the blue key. Go to 44 (**the room with repeated numbers**) and take the crystal key. Go to 63 (**room with largest numbers**), and take our cool million dollars.

### 3. You merely have to become an expert archer

> Retrace all the way back to room 37 and open the blue box. We found the batteries for the teleporter in room 5! (**sfuspqfmfu** Caesared and backwards, **84 69 76 69 80 79 82 84 69 82** in UTF-8 character table.) Proceed to the teleporter and go to room 30 (**11110** in binary). Go to 42 (**the answer**) and then to 10 (**X** Roman numeral). Take the arrow and press the yellow button. A secret passage opens from 18 (**3s2 3p6** is Argon electron orbitals) room. It leads to room 23 (◔◈◅ ◌●◒◄ ◉◓ ◍◙ ◓◈◅◐◅◒◄, ◉ ◌◁◃○ ◎●◔◈◉◎◇, decoded through character values to THE LORD IS MY SHEPERD, ETC, which is Psalm 23.) But first we fall into 21. (**NPPSTVPJWFSQFIUGPGMBITJSFCNVOFIUFTPIX** Caesared backwards, half of the PREVIOUS room number is half of 42 is 21.)

### 4. You only need to summon a Greek god

> From 21, we can get a red key (**[Russian]**). Unlock the red door to go to 13 (**bad luck room**), and find a **D**. But what is a **D**? Well, a bow, of course (look at the shape). Retrace our steps and use our bow and arrow to shoot the bullseye in 30, opening a passage from 26 (**1A** hex) to 56 (**Japanese kanji numbers**). Take the passage and obtain the magic book. It can summon the power of Poseidon to create a bridge over troubled waters (**[backwards Greek message]**).

### 5. You just have to walk on rainbows

> We are warped to the starting room, but after returning to 56 again we are warped to 59 (**first two-digit room number appearing in π**). Take the green (**TERRA** Caesared) key and proceed to 18 (**dezoito** in Portugese). Open the green door and go to 2 (**first prime number**). Take the parachute (**☏☀☑☀☂☇☔☓☄**, unicode character values). Proceed to 8 (**this room cubed**). Read from the magic book, summoning a bridge. Go to 28 (**perfect number**). Take the gold! I have no idea what **that girls** is supposed to be, but whatever it is, eat a pill and go to 37 (**naM hsaM** backwards, Action 52 index.) Give the gold to the gnome. Use the parachute to survive the fall.

### And finally...

> Return to the dungeon, enter room 1 (the exit), and say hello to the princess.

### Mysteries left unsolved **

1. What is "that girls"?
2. What does **kwws=22elw1o|24vSg{I}** mean?

> Wait, no, I got this one. Caesar it three back and follow the URL to find a trollface. Good one, Victor.

3. What does **@@@@@@@@** mean?
4. Where does the **21120110122101211011201112** pill lead?

> Probably 37, because that's where two of the others lead (Japanese Pokemon name and Mash Man action 52 index.) But Pidgeotto is 17 (Pokedex index), so I'm not sure.

5. Is 26 not the **iron room** after all? (See Martin's comment).
6. Is room 40 a Portal-esque red herring?

Comment: I have a feeling that the iron room is not 26, because 26 has a door leading to the iron room.

Comment: Well, shucks. I'll try to figure that out, but I think it's OK: whatever the iron room is, we can go to there and then to 26.

Comment: You are in the right way, but you can't take all the pills at the same time in room 12, just one each time. I will edit the question to clarify this. Further, really, you can't shoot an arrow without a bow, so if you really want to shoot the arrow, you will need a bow. And last, how do you come back after leaving the dungeon?

Comment: I assume since technically he escaped, he could walk back through the front door which would be the first room (1) get the princess and go? it does not state where you land.

Comment: @Oblongamous Yes. Exacttly.

Comment: The "NPPSTVPJWFSQFIUGPGMBITJSFCNVOFIUFTPIX" you decoded right, but interpreted its meaning wrong, it is not 5.

Comment: Ah, OK. When I interpret  "NPPSTVPJWFSQFIUGPGMBITJSFCNVOFIUFTPIX" correctly, I can get that bow. Also, since I only need one of the pills, am I allowed to take that pill out of the pill room?

Comment: About the unsolved mysteries: 1. That is very easy, but you got it wrong, it is not 21, it is not a video; 2. hahahahahaha; 3. This is one of the easiest, can't give a hint without telling the answer; 4. You are on the right track. I will only say that this one is decoded in an unique way differently from any other encrypted text; 5. I can't tell you without giving the answer for free.

Comment: For @@@@@@@@, it's not just 8, is it? I'll think about the others. Also, this puzzle is awesome. :D

Comment: You're backtracking a lot through rooms that aren't actually connected. The question clarified now that every door is unidirectional.

Comment: I added a magic bean in room 23 to fix a bug. Sorry for seeing it so late.