# Puzzle Dungeon: The Intro

Tags: cipher, password, find-the-order

Inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4730/escape-the-dungeon-by-deciphering-the-codes-and-navigating-the-rooms-to-find-a) that I found by looking randomly at the top-voted puzzles up to page 7. Don't question it.

> In the magical land of Puzzlandia (I am very creative at making up names), there is one dungeon. A very big dungeon. Everyone who has entered has not come out.
>
> So of course, you're going to do the smart thing and barge in without any items.
>
> You enter the dungeon in Room 1, and the door slams shut behind you.
>
> There's no way out right here, so you'll have to go even deeper into the dungeon. Your goal right now is to make it to the second floor (which will be in the second part of this)
>
> (Remember to put your answers in spoiler quotes, and explain your path)
>
> Passages are one-way in the dungeon, unless otherwise mentioned.
>
> You can't take an item or go down a path unless you've decrypted it.
>
> More parts of this will be coming! :D
>
> Good luck. Maybe next time bring something.

#### Room 1:

> This is the only room that isn't in spoiler quotes, because it's the starting room.
>
> **yhbtzpggftveucndmikb** is scratched into the opposite wall.
>
> There is a door on the left that leads to room **panic in the afternoon.**
>
> There is a door on the right that leads to room **4 divided by 1/2.**

#### Room 2:

> As soon as you enter this room, it begins filling with lava! You flee to room $837428347729347827492843794728734792^0$.

#### Room 3:

> There is a goblin in this room. If your combat power is **1** or above, you can kill the goblin. After the encounter, you go to room **sides of a pentagon minus legs of a tripod.**

#### Room 4:

> There is a door that leads back to room **german no less four.** 
>  
>  There is also a **button labeled 'Pointless Button.'**

#### Room 5:

> There is a door in this room leading to room **RUASUNEV**. 
>  
>  There is a door in this room leading to room **1010**.

#### Room 6:

> You found a **19-23-9-20-3-8**! 
>  
>  You can now turn **back to the last room you were in.**

#### Room 7:

> There is a staircase here to room $2^4$ (in the episode 2 that is coming)... but a dragon guarding it. You need to pay the dragon **10 gold coins**. Otherwise, he eats you and you get a GAME OVER.

#### Room 8:

> There are **3 gold coins** in this room. 
>  
>  There is a hole in the wall. If you have a **3/3/2017 console**, you can put it here. If you do, you can read the info under 'exited raichu is a nerd'.
>  
>  There is a door on the left leading to room **evif**.

#### Room 9:

> There is **a rusty sword** in this room. It increases your combat power by **1**, but you must use a hand to hold it. 
>  
>  There is a doorway leading to **the square root of this room**. 
>  
>  There is a doorway leading to room **kwhsbrkbetdvjsemggnffp**.

#### Room 10:

> There are **7 gold coins** in this room. 
>  
>  There is a **jxtkteiue** in this room. **qqiekrmxsvaywrrtwmjxtgwwmobpbhzbesctgludcsbrsvihikdkwhwidzb**. 
>  
>  There is a door in this room leading to room **Kanto fire starter.**

#### Killing the Goblin:

> The goblin was carrying a paper with the words **"I am the key."**

#### Pressing the Pointless Button:

> Nothing happens. **Cvbelvjmpfmkvsde?**

#### excited raichu is a nerd:

> A secret passageway opens from room **ein** to room **sept**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First I

> head to room 9 (Nine in the afternoon, song by Panic! at the Disco)

then I

> take the sword

then I

> head to room 3 (Square root of 9)

then I

> slay the goblin, receiving his paper indicating goblin is the cipher key for encrypted text

and

> leave to room 2, (5 sides - 3 legs)

and

> flee back to room 1.

then

> go to 9 again

and

> head to room 6 (kwhsbrkbetdvjsemggnffp decrypted by 'goblin' -> eighteendividedbythree, or 6)

and

> take the SWITCH (numbers to letters, alphabetical order)

then

> hit rooms 3, 2, 1 as before.

and

> head to room 8, (4 / 0.5)

and

> grab the 3 coins, and place the SWITCH to learn of secret passage from 1 to 7 (ein, sept)

then

> go to room 5, (evif backwards)

and

> leave to room 10 (decimal from binary 1010)

then

> take the 7 gold coins, totaling 10

and

> leave for room 4 (charmander, #4)

and

> push the pointless button, nothing happens. (what did I expect?)

and

> go to room 5 again (nein - four)

then

> go to room 3 (ruasunev backwards is venusaur, #3)

and

> pass by the goblin corpse

and

> flee lava again back to room 1

then

> pass through secret passage to room 7

and

> give dragon my 10 coins

and

> ascend the staircase

of course I was in too much of a hurry to leave and didn't identify what was

> in room 10 with the coins...

Comment: Good job! Can you explain the cipher portion for me though? I got the key and the text, but couldn't reverse it. Also, how does ein = 1?

Comment: The cipher is a running key cipher where the key repeats and is used as an offset for the ciphertext. I used http://practicalcryptography.com/ciphers/running-key-cipher/

and

Germanic languages use 'ein' in general to mean 'a' or 'one of something', and it felt correct

Comment: Thank you @Emnepho! Going back through with your help, it worked as vinegere instead of running though.